# Why won't "cmd.exe /C command" end when called via Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, process, cmd

I'm trying to run a command via command prompt from an ASP.Net web application. I can see the process start in task manager on the web server, however the process just sits there and never exits nor does it run the commands I specified.

```
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C " +command;
            startInfo.UserName = "myuser";
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.Domain = "mydomain";
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            String pass = "mypass";
            System.Security.SecureString secPass = new System.Security.SecureString();

            foreach (char c in pass.ToCharArray())
            {
                secPass.AppendChar(c);
            }
            secPass.MakeReadOnly();

            startInfo.Password = secPass;

            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            //output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();
```

I've tried both with and without reading the standard output.

The application will hang on `process.WaitForExit();` until I kill the process via task manager.

Comment: If you try it reading the standard output, have you looked at what the standard output is?  Try reading standard error as well;  you may be getting some sort of error message, maybe one that even says "Push any key to continue..." or something to that effect.

Comment: @GWLlosa, both standard output and standard error are empty. I thought about that "Push any key..." so I tried writing a character to the standard input, but still nothing.

Comment: Why run it through cmd? Why not just run it direct?

Comment: Ran the same code on a different box (not a web server) and it worked fine. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @David Heffernan, because i'm not sure what I may want to run in the future.

Comment: @Petey That makes no sense to me, sorry. Best of luck with your endeavour.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the specific command you are trying to execute. Can you post it? Sure there are no alerts "hidden" by the execution under asp.net user?

Comment: @BertuPG, I've tried a bunch of different commands: "echo test > C:\test.txt" "ipconfig" "exit", none work. I'm assuming it is a permissions problem, but i'm not sure what i would change to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we need to understand what commands you are actually trying to process in order to determine what's going on.  Also we need to know what OS the server is running.

For example, I did see in your comments where you tried "echo test > C:\test.txt"  Under Windows Server 2008 (and Windows 7) the root directory requires administrator permissions in order to create files.  If this is executing under IIS, my guess is that your IIS user isn't an administrator and you are getting security exceptions.

Also, a number of commands may require elevated priviledges due to UAC.  I don't remember exactly, but I'm guessing that if those commands are being caught by UAC then the process is waiting for UAC confirmation... Which I *believe* you cannot supply via a command line.

This type of problem won't be seen if you log into the machine and execute it directly... unless you are logging in with the worker process user account.

So, the very first thing you need to do is figure out what it is you are trying to run and see if the user the worker process is executing under can even perform those actions.  Security is there to protect you, so be careful about granting additional permissions to the user.

The reason why it might work on one machine versus another again depends on the OS's those machines are running and the configuration of the user the commands are executing under.

If this is truly a security issue, as I suspect, then you should post a question on serverfault.com to ask what permission sets you need to execute various commands under your worker process user.

You might look at the machines event logs to see if there were any warnings or errors thrown about the command.  Sometimes things like this can show up there to give you a bit more information as to what happened.

Comment: Wow.  I just saw how old this question is...  oops.

Comment: I don't mind, thanks for your input. Had forgotten about it actually. It was a permissions issue.

Answer (score 2):

Once passed to CMD, the control has passed to the shell.  It's better to add a close it like this:

```
private void closeSubProcess()
    {
        Process[] currentProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process p in currentProcesses)
        {
            string s = p.ProcessName;
            s = s.ToLower();
            if (s.CompareTo("YOURPROGRAMNAMEHERE") == 0)
            {
                p.CloseMainWindow();
                p.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is likely to result in closing the process before it has done whatever it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: True, you would need to make a file or update something to tell the .NET part that it's done and then fire it off.

Answer (score 0):

I am calling cmd.exe to start a node module in Windows. npm obviously must be installed first, along with the node module I need, and then I can call the module with args in C#.  Problem was, the cmd.exe would not shut off, I'd have to use Task Mgr (just like this question!).

```
        //This requires npm, and the module installed by npm...
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.UseShellExecute = true; //closes command window
        psi.Arguments = "/c <nodemodulename>" + file1 + ".txt " + file2 + ".log";
        Process p = Process.Start(psi);
        p.Close();
```

The `/c` argument was key to closing down cmd.exe.  When I started out, I had put in the `/K` argument, which keeps the darned thing running.  Solved.  Hope this helps.  (This is like ancient, but we always forget)

Comment: (I realize the original question had the /c argument, but I thought it would be good to offer this up anyway (/K vs /c).  I wish you well.